# Is it possible to open a serial port multiple times?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I'm designing a control system which should handle too many actuators (or sets of actuators) over a serial port. The new design (not implemented yet) is supposed to control actuators over multiple POSIX threads.

Is this possible to open a serial port multiple times (by multiple threads)?
If yes, I'm gonna write a synchronous write / asynchronous read mechanism. There will be `n` threads `M[0]` to `M[n-1]` which can write data directly to serial port. They're not supposed to read from serial port directly. Instead, a thread `R` is supposed to read data from port in a `while(true)` loop and serve data to corresponding threads waiting for it. (Wake up `M[i]` which is waiting for response, when data is ready and it belongs to `i`th thread)

It's all depended on the question if it's possible to write to serial port by multiple threads or not.

**notes**: I can't test the behavior of serial port, because currently I have no access to devices in mechatronics lab of my university,

I'm using kernel 2.6.38-8 patched with Xenomai real-time subsystem (if important)

I'm porting code to traditional Linux way of communicating with serial port. (Open `/dev/ttyS0`, set baudrate, `read()`, `write()`, etc.) Currently a third party library is used to talk with serial port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the same serial port only once. The second trial fails with Access Denied. Once the port is opened, you can work with it in different threads, using the port handle. Of course, you need to synchronize port access between these threads.

Comment: I'm trying to write a lockless code. Did you mean somehow to protect code section containing the `wite()` system call with a `mutex`? Is something wrong with two threads trying to write to port in same time?

Comment: write operation is not atomic, so results are undefined, if different write calls are not synchronized.

Comment: If you insist on lockless, (and I can't see much point in that re. serial calls), use a lock-free queue to communicate your tx. buffer/string pointers to one thread that does the writes.  You will still need signaling on the queue, semaphore or something, to elimiate spining, but you would then have 'lock-free', for what it's worth.